# Garbage collection logging format

Tags: logging, garbage-collection

I am using Java 1.8 in one of my applications. How can I force GC to output log in plain text format and NOT in XML format ?

Please look at the below mentioned kind of logs what I am getting and What I expect it to be.

**OBSERVED LOGS:**

```
<exclusive-start id="2" timestamp="2018-06-18T01:41:50.395" intervalms="26599.320">
  <response-info timems="0.014" idlems="0.014" threads="0" lastid="0000000001FE3700" lastname="main" />
</exclusive-start>
<af-start id="3" threadId="0000000001FE4060" totalBytesRequested="40232" timestamp="2018-06-18T01:41:50.395" intervalms="26599.466" type="nursery" />
<cycle-start id="4" type="scavenge" contextid="0" timestamp="2018-06-18T01:41:50.396" intervalms="26600.656" />
<gc-start id="5" type="scavenge" contextid="4" timestamp="2018-06-18T01:41:50.397">
  <mem-info id="6" free="803864072" total="1073741824" percent="74">
    <mem type="nursery" free="0" total="268435456" percent="0">
      <mem type="allocate" free="0" total="134217728" percent="0" />
      <mem type="survivor" free="0" total="134217728" percent="0" />
    </mem>
    <mem type="tenure" free="803864072" total="805306368" percent="99">
      <mem type="soa" free="763599368" total="765041664" percent="99" />
      <mem type="loa" free="40264704" total="40264704" percent="100" />
    </mem>
    <remembered-set count="21177" />
  </mem-info>
</gc-start>
```

**DESIRED LOGS:**

```
34.927: [GC [PSYoungGen: 146575K->21818K(152896K)] 146575K->31648K(502464K), 0.1226880 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.02, real=0.12 secs]
38.705: [GC [PSYoungGen: 152890K->21817K(152896K)] 162720K->72539K(502464K), 1.6407590 secs] [Times: user=0.27 sys=0.05, real=1.64 secs]
45.687: [GC [PSYoungGen: 138376K->21812K(85056K)] 189099K->73548K(434624K), 0.2931950 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.29 secs]
```

Comment: You should switch to OpenJDK or Oracle JDK. Now it seems you are using Java from IBM.

Comment: @AlexeyRagozin That's correct. Earlier I was using Oracle JDK 1.6 and now I am using IBM JDK 1.8. I understand there will be different algorithms for gc logging for different vendors. However, I was just wondering if it could be controlled by an additional JVM argument(not sure what it'd be).